# Android - Detecting touched element while performing drag and drop

Tags: android, xamarin, drag-and-drop

[image]

I have a drag and drop list implementation in Xamarin. The problem is that I want to be able to drag and drop element only when the drag and drop button is touched not the whole element.

I was trying to detect for the ImageView being pressed but I am unable to get the correct hit ImageView.

```
public bool OnDown (MotionEvent e) { 
            int x = (int) e.GetX();
            int y = (int) e.GetY();
            int itemnum = PointToPosition(x, y);
            if (itemnum == AdapterView.InvalidPosition) {
                return false;
            }

            if (m_dragging != null) {
                m_dragging.Stop();
                m_dragging = null;
            }

            View item = GetChildAt(itemnum - FirstVisiblePosition);
            item.Pressed = false;

            var dragImage = item.FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.drag_image);

            Rect bounds = new Rect();
            dragImage.GetDrawingRect (bounds);
            if (!bounds.Contains (x, y)) {
                return false;
            }
```

The following code works only for the first element in the list and does not apply to any other. I am suspecting that the detection of hit is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved followingly. I realized that I actually do not need to care about the Y axis and it's enough to take just X axis in account.

```
// Detect if the user is actually pressing the drag and drop image or not.
            var dragImage = item.FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.drag_image);
            if (dragImage != null) {
                var dragImageHitRect = new Rect ();
                dragImage.GetDrawingRect (dragImageHitRect);
                // In this case we do not care about the Y axis. Just compare the x axis.
                if (!dragImageHitRect.Contains (x, (int)dragImage.GetY ())) { 
                    return false;
                }
            }
```